# How to integrate jersey + spring jpa?

Tags: spring, jersey, spring-data-jpa

While integrating with jersey + jpa i face error that is regarding to mapping the resources and also request is not found the controller . Following is the error that i face while running the app

```
10:43:34.616 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher' processing GET request for [/xptraining/]
10:43:34.618 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/xptraining/] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
10:43:34.618 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

    <display-name>xptraining</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/rest.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: See example https://github.com/psamsotha/jersey-spring-example